# Style.css дочерней темы загружается дважды

Tags: wordpress, style

В процессе доработки темы, увидел что стили дочерней темы грузятся дважды, одна автоматически, с текущей версией wordpress, а другая собственно с версией, которая указана в самом style.css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В официальной документации говорится, что идеальным способом подключения, является тот, когда вызов дочерних стилей идет прямо из основной темы, что приводит у меня к повторной загрузке.

Вот что имеется в коде сторонней темы и в ее документации по подключению дочерней темы:

(код из основной темы, который подключает дочерние стили после основных)

```
    public function child_scripts() {
        if ( is_child_theme() ) {
            $child_theme = wp_get_theme( get_stylesheet() );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'shoptimizer-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), $child_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
        }
    }
```

(Код из документации темы, для подключения дочерних стилей в дочернем functions.php)

```
$parent_style    = 'shoptimizer-style';
$parent_base_dir = 'shoptimizer';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(),
wp_get_theme( $parent_base_dir ) ? wp_get_theme( $parent_base_dir )->get( 'Version' ) : '' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'shoptimizer-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version') );
```

Хотелось бы узнать как можно этого избежать, не отключая код из основной темы

Даже удалив весь код подключения во втором примере, они все равно грузятся кодом из первого примера. Раньше не было таких проблем с другими темами, но и просто вырезать куски от разработчиков не хочется, ведь они явно лучше понимают, как подключать стили

Может кто нибудь еще знает в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

Дочерняя тема - это Ваше рабочее пространство. Оттуда Вы можете свободно удалить подключение стиля.

Вы просто сделали лишнюю работу в дочерней теме, т.к. разработчик уже предусмотрел автоматическое подключение из дочерней.